# Should I use the java.net or org.apache.http library for HTTP in my Java application?

Tags: java, apache, http, networking

What should I know about the trade-offs between these two HTTP libraries?

Comment: See [What is the best Java library to use for HTTP POST, GET etc.?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322335/what-is-the-best-java-library-to-use-for-http-post-get-etc)

Comment: close-voters, this is not an exact duplicate of the question you referenced. The other OP asked for `the best` HTTP lib, this one for a decision aid on two specific libs.

Answer (score 4):

Depends on your needs I would say. I used the java.net one while doing simple GETs and POSTs. Suddenly I needed support for session cookies etc, and I switched to the HTTPClient.

That's also my general recommendation. Don't introduces dependencies on third-party libraries for simple tasks that can be easily done without.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the apache library is easy to use and reliable, but as aioobe said introduces external dependencies (given that has apache license that should not be a problem for commercial products). IMHO if you have to handle a lot of simultaneous connections I will go for the apache lib as the performance will be probably better.

Check this article: http://lassewesth.blogspot.com.es/2009/05/i-like-apache-http-client-over.html