# Best java lib for http connections?

Tags: java

hi all I'm writing a simple web crawling script that needs to connect to a webpage, follow the 302 redirects automatically, give me the final url from the link and let me grab the html.

What's the preferred java lib for doing these kinds of things?

thanks

Comment: Take a look - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322335/what-is-the-best-java-library-to-use-for-http-post-get-etc

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [Apache HttpComponents Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client/) for this (or "plain vanilla" the Java SE builtin and verbose [`URLConnection`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests) API). For the HTML parsing/traversing/manipulation part [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org) may be [useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152138/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-the-leading-java-html-parsers/3154281#3154281).

Note that a bit decent crawler should obey the [robots.txt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard). You may want to take a look at existing Java based webcrawlers, like <strike>[J-Spider](http://www.mksearch.mkdoc.org/research/spiders/j-spider/)</strike> [Apache Nutch](http://nutch.apache.org/about.html).

Answer (score 2):

As BalusC said, have a look at Apache's HttpComponents Client. The Nutch project has solved lots of hard crawling/fetching/indexing problems, so if if you want to see how they solve the following 302, have a look at http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/nutch/trunk/src/

Comment: That's actually a better suggestion than J-Spider.