# How to declare a file in html

Tags: html, file

So there is this code

```
<div>DROP!<button onclick="document.querySelector('input').click()">Or click</button>    </div>
<input style="visibility: collapse; width: 0px;" type="file" onchange="upload(this.files[0])">

<script>


window.ondragover = function(e) {e.preventDefault()}
window.ondrop = function(e) {e.preventDefault(); upload(e.dataTransfer.files[0]); }
function upload(file) {

    if (!file || !file.type.match(/image.*/)) return;
```

And what it does is take a file from the user, checks if it's an image and then does something. How can I make it so that instead of letting the user select the image I select the path of the image and then it does what it's supposed to do. So like declare the file I think.

Answer (score 1):

A webpage does not have permission to select a file from a visitor's computer. That would be a serious security risk (e.g. Popular accounting software stores its data in file X by default, webpage selects that file, reads it, and sends the data to the site owner).

All selections of local files on a webpage must be performed by the user.

Comment: So I can't give it the path of a file. Any other way I can do this without the user having to input the location?

Comment: Correct. No, that would be a security hole.

Comment: Another quick question, is there anyway I can integrate this with a Java program? And when a file is made with Java use this to upload it?

Comment: Assuming that by "Java program" you mean "A Java application" (as opposed to a Java applet or a Java servlet), then that program can upload the file and not involve a webpage or browser or JavaScript at all. Just find a suitable HTTP client library for Java.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322335/what-is-the-best-java-library-to-use-for-http-post-get-etc