# Curl command using java which give Json file and to read the JSon file

Tags: java, curl

I have a curl command:

```
curl -o map.json http://localhost:8091/pools/default/buckets/travel-sample"
```

How I will execute using Java. The command will give me the `JSON` file, which I have to use to get some attributes from it.

Comment: You need HTTP client or read URL as resource.

Comment: Why do you have to call curl as opposed to, say, using any of the numerous HTTP APIs that are out there?

Comment: As I wanted to execute this command in the server which gives me whole data of what I want.

Comment: What the comments are suggesting is instead of trying to use `curl` to make the request, use [a HTTP Java library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322335/what-is-the-best-java-library-to-use-for-http-post-get-etc).  Most will also parse the json into a java class for you as well which will make the response much easier to use in your java code.

Answer (score 1):

You can execute your command with :

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("curl -o map.json http://localhost:8091/pools/default/buckets/travel-sample")
```

It is rather problematic command see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483830/process-waitfor-never-returns)
Downloaded json should be in map.json file after executing command. You can read it using [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) util:

```
FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("map.json"))
```

Full example is:

```
Process process;
try {
    process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("curl -o map.json http://localhost:8091/pools/default/buckets/travel-sample");
    process.waitFor();
    System.out.println(FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("map.json")));
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```